# What happens when Django Session timesout?

Tags: python, django

In my scenario the function which does some backend updates is called when request is submitted takes a lot of time to return the value and as a result the session times out.

So my doubt is

1. What happens in backend when session times out?
2. Does the function that was running stops running immediately as session timesout?
3. Will the data from django session table be removed?

I don't know much about django sessions and reading online didn't gave much clarity on doubts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your code on backend that handles HTTP request continues to run when the request times out.